# How to convert an UTF string with scandinavian characters to ASCII?

Tags: python, ascii, utf

I would like to convert this string

```
foo_utf = u'nästy chäräctörs with å and co.' # unicode
```

into this

```
foo_ascii = 'nästy chäräctörs with å and co.' # ASCII
```

.

Any idea how to do this in Python (2.6)? I found [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) module but I have no idea how to do the transformation.

Comment: ascii does not have å ä ö and others, do you want something else, e.g.  iso 8859-1(latin-1) or utf-8 ?

Comment: I probably have to reformulate the question a bit. I ran into the issue while developing a template tag for Django. I noticed it works just fine when using regular strings but fails while using an exactly similar unicode string.

Comment: Your top string is not any form of UTF.  UTF are unicode encodings, which means that they are sequences of bytes which represent unicode characters.  What you have is a unicode string, which is a sequence of characters.  The number of bytes in each is irrelevant, and impossible to determine from within python.  The distinction is not mere pedantry.  Understanding what python is doing with your text will help you avoid those pesky `Unicode{En,De}codeError` s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really is a Django question, and not a python one.
if the string is in one of your .py files, make sure that you have the following line on top of your file:
`-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

furthermore, your string needs to be of type "unicode"  (u'foobar')

And then make sure that your html page works in unicode:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

That should do the whole trick. No encoding/decoding etc. necessary, just make sure that everything is unicode, and you are on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for excellent pointers. I managed to trace the issue down to a str conversion in the code that broke it apart. I found other comments insightful as well. :)

Comment: Also, actually save the file in utf-8 so it agrees with the coding declaration.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can.  Those "nästy chäräctörs" can't be encoded as ASCII, so you'll have to pick a different encoding (UTF-8 or Latin-1 or Windows-1252 or something).

Comment: This is true.  ASCII contains only 127 characters and none with diacritical marks.  It's possible to convert it to ANSI if you select the correct code page.  In any case, it's best to stick with Unicode unless you have no other choice.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `encode` method of string.

```
>>> u'nästy chäräctörs with å and co.'.encode('latin-1')
'n\xe4sty ch\xe4r\xe4ct\xf6rs with \xe5 and co.'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several options in the `codecs` module in python's stdlib, depending on how you want the extended characters handled:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> u = u'nästy chäräctörs with å and co.'
>>> encode = codecs.get_encoder('ascii')
>>> encode(u) 
'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> encode(u, 'ignore')
('nsty chrctrs with  and co.', 31)
>>> encode(u, 'replace')
('n?sty ch?r?ct?rs with ? and co.', 31)
>>> encode(u, 'xmlcharrefreplace')
('n&#228;sty ch&#228;r&#228;ct&#246;rs with &#229; and co.', 31)
>>> encode(u, 'backslashreplace')
('n\\xe4sty ch\\xe4r\\xe4ct\\xf6rs with \\xe5 and co.', 31)
```

Hopefully one of those will meet your needs.  There's more information available in the [Python codecs module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the unicodedata module (http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) provided in python to convert a lot of unicode values into an Ascii variant. IE fix the different "s and such. Follow that up by the encode() method and you can completely clean up a string.

The method you mainly what out of the unicodedata is normalize and pass it the NFKC flag.